# How does Future.sequence work?

Tags: scala

In Scala, I want to transform a variable of type `List[Future[T]]` into `Future[List[T]]`.

I know I can use `Future.sequence`.

How is `Future.sequence` implemented though?

Comment: It's basically a `foldLeft` with a successful future as accumulator, just check the source code of `Future.scala`.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L663

Comment: Before looking, why not try to implement on your own?

Answer (score 1):

[Like this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L499):

```
/** Simple version of `Futures.traverse`. 
 *  Transforms a `TraversableOnce[Future[A]]` into a `Future[TraversableOnce[A]]`.
 *  Useful for reducing many `Future`s into a single `Future`.
 */
def sequence[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]]
            (in: M[Future[A]])
            (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[Future[A]], A, M[A]], 
             executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]] = {
  in.foldLeft(successful(cbf(in))) {
    (fr, fa) => for (r <- fr; a <- fa) yield (r += a)
  }.map(_.result())(InternalCallbackExecutor)
}
```

It creates a seed `Future` for `foldLeft` using `Promise.successful` and then uses a `CanBuildFrom` to accumulate all the futures into a sequence, yielding the result of the accumulation at the end.

Comment: If you're confused by `CanBuildFrom`, as I have been, then I recommend Chapter 25 of [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed).